# Card swipe/flip effect using CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to figure out how the card swipe/flip effect was done as seen on this site: http://catalystconference.com/ (under the "Our Favorites" and similar sections).  Can this be accomplished using only CSS?

Comment: (1) What have you actually tried? (2) If you do, would you show us your code so far? (preferably in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com))

Comment: @Deekey Don't post spam comments trying to attract attention to your answers. We can all see your answer.

Comment: @Terry Here's the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sigep23/TTv4q/

It's close, but not exactly what I'm looking for like the site I referenced in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on text-indent, because it forces the browser to actually render the negative space that you have specified. Instead, try using absolute positioning and left/top/bottom/right properties to help position (and subsequently reveal/hide) your hidden pane.

For your HTML, I have taken the liberty to create two panes in your `<div>`: a visible and a hidden one.

```
<div>
    <p class="pane-visible">Visible pane.</p>
    <p class="pane-hidden">Hidden pane.</p>
</div>
```

CSS wise, the visible pane is positioned as is, but the hidden pane is positioned absolutely (but relative to its parent) that is 100% off from the top (therefore sits at the bottom of the parent container, but out of sight). The trick is to change the `top` property of the hidden pane when the parent is hovered, to bring it to the top. The animation is easily done with the CSS3 property: `transition`.

```
div {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
div > p[class|="pane"] {    /* Targets element with the class "pane-" (notice the dash) */
    box-sizing: border-box;    /* Forces width and height to be at 300px even with padding */
    padding: 1em;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
    div > p[class*="hidden"] {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        transition: all .25s ease-in-out; /* You might want to add vendor prefixes */
    }
        div:hover > p[class*="hidden"] {
            top: 0;
        }
```

Here is my proof-of-concept fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/TTv4q/2/

Comment: @sigep23 Do accept the answer if it has helped :)